# Multiple IP addresses on one NIC register twice in DNS server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ip, nic

We've got a build server (Windows Server 2008 SP2, 64-bit) which has one NIC and two IP addresses registered to that NIC (192.168.1.30 and 192.168.1.31). The build server is  registering two identical Host (A) records for itself in our DNS server:

- buildserver.example.com => 192.168.1.30
- buildserver.example.com => 192.168.1.31

I know in the "Advanced TCP/IP Settings" window for the build server's NIC, under the "DNS" tab, there is a check box labeled "Register this connection's addresses in DNS". I only want ONE of the IP addresses (ending in .30) to be registered in DNS not both of them. Can that be done?

My best guess is to disable the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" and manually add the Host (A) record to our DNS server.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I think you're probably on the money with the removal of "Register this connection" and manually adding the host.  From my understanding, that setting will apply at the NIC level meaning all IPs bound to that NIC will be affected and added to DNS.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I ended up doing just that - disabling "Register this connection" and manually entered the Host (A) records in the DNS server.

Comment: Marcus, Put this comment into the answer box. So it can be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with server that hosts multiple IPs on single network card. On name resolving on other machines I was getting random one of those IPs. Since I don't control DNS server (and it was Friday late at night) I removed all IPs except one, check "Register this connection's address in DNS, verified on other machines that DNS lookup returns the address that I wanted. Then I cleared "Register this..." and added other IP addresses. So far it works.

Update: But after first reboot of the server it again registered other (wrong) IP address

Update: There is a [hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975808/EN-US) for Server 2008 to prevent registration of multiple IP addresses. After the hotfix create new IP address using:

> Netsh int ipv4 add address < Interface Name > < ip address > skipassource=true

Comment: That will only be a temporary fix.  If the one address is not re-registered, eventually the savaging will remove the DNS entry (assuming it is turned on).

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a virtual environment it's pretty normal to just add a second NIC to separate your DNS registrations.

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh int ipv4 add address <interface_name> <ip_address> skipassource=true
```

is not successful, as it will not add in locally but in DNS server it will get added and make an host A entry.

So the best option is to disable the "Register this connection's addresses in DNS" and manually add the Host (A) record to our DNS server. This really works.